# Cakephp and memcached

Tags: cakephp, memcached

I'm trying to get memcached working with my cake install.

I have a shared cakephp folder as per:

```
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html
```

My webroot/inidex.php has the line

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS . 'var' . DS . 'cakephp25' . DS . 'lib');
```

So this points all my apps to use /var/cakephp25/ as it's lib folder.

However when I turn on memcached with:

```
$engine = 'Memcached';
```

in core.php I get:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in /var/cakephp25/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 179
```